# Prove $B$ is a Lebesgue measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Suppose $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $$B=\cup_{x\in A}[x-1,x+1]$$
>   Prove $B$ is a Lebesgue measurable.

Do we just need to check for all $E\subset X$ we have $m(E)=m(E\cap B)+m(E\cap B^c)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$B=B_1\cup B_2\cup B_3$ where
$$B_1=\bigcup_{x\in A}(x-1,x+1),$$
$$B_2=\{x+1:x\in A\}$$
and
$$B_3=\{x-1:x\in A\}.$$
Then $B_1$ is open, so Lebesgue measurable, and $B_2$ and $B_3$ are translates
of $A$, so Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: Why $B_1$ is open? I mean why $(x-1, x+1)$ is open? Just a ball?

Comment: @BobOakley A union of open sets is open. Open intervals are open sets.